# How many time for put waypoint to database

Tags: flutter, leaflet

For Leaflet and Flutter (and more other develop).
How many points it needs to save for memorize steps of a path where I walk?

I put some seconds... Or is better meters?

I am developing a web map can be live update with flutter app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.